# How to change the datatype of a column from integer to money?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, alter-table, money

I am attempting to convert a PostgreSQL table column from integer to money, but I am receiving the error:

> cannot cast type MyColumn to money

I have tried these two statements, but just haven't found any real example on how to really do it.

```
ALTER TABLE products 
    ALTER COLUMN price TYPE money
```

and:

```
ALTER TABLE products 
    ALTER COLUMN price TYPE money USING to_char(price, '999.99')
```

How can you change the datatype of a PostgreSQL column from integer to money?

Comment: What version of postgres are you running?

Answer (score 9):

Just try the following command.

```
ALTER TABLE products ALTER COLUMN price TYPE money using price::text::money
```

Non-quoted numeric values can be converted to money by casting the numeric value to text and then money

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
ALTER TABLE products 
    ALTER COLUMN price TYPE money USING price::money
```

btw what error did you get on your second try up there?

Answer (score 4):

As [francs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2135/francs) already implied, there is [no default cast from integer to money](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-money.html) (until [9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-money.html)), instead you need an intermediate cast to text:

```
select 78::integer::money;
ERROR:  cannot cast type integer to money
LINE 1: select 78::integer::money;
                          ^
select 78::integer::text::money;
 money
--------
 £78.00
```

Your error is subtle however. Note that while `select to_char(78, '999.99')::money` succeeds, the following fails:

```
alter table products alter column price type money using to_char(price, '999.99');
ERROR:  column "price" cannot be cast to type money
```

but with an explicit cast it succeeds:

```
alter table products alter column price type money using to_char(price, '999.99')::money;
ALTER TABLE
```

this looks like a bug to me - I do not have 9.0 or 9.1 to test on yet, hopefully someone else can't say if it is fixed in those versions or if we should raise it as a bug.

---

aside: your original will of course fail even with an explicit cast if there are any rows where price>=1000:

```
alter table products alter column price type money using to_char(price, '999.99')::money;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type money: " ###.##"
```

Comment: hehe, and here I was gonna suggest inserting a new column, updating into via convert, then deleting the old one (but see I think like a programmer :P )